# How can i export data from grid to excel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I see the extjs 6.0.0 api has `{ptype:gridexporter}`,and I import the ext-all.js into my template.But it still error.
I just want to export the grid to excel.
Thanks.

Comment: See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Exporter

Comment: I would refer also to this theme on forum https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305642 . For our project I have extended the grid to make the stuff https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?304751-Exportable-in-xlsx-grid. But this solution need 2 additional libraries, but it exported an xlsx instead of xml.